# php + image upload from html form

Tags: php, html, video, web

I am new to using php and html and am wondering if someone can tell me where I am going wrong in my code.  I am trying to upload a mp4 movie(don't know if that is the problem) and that portion of the form is always coming back as being empty.  The videos are located in the same directory as my php code.

HTML code

```
<input type = 'file' name = 'sonogram'/>
```

PHP code

```
Codefunction addImage($studyId)
{
  //check to make sure they have uploaded a sonogram
  if(!empty($_FILES['sonogram']))
    $sonogram = $_FILES['sonogram'];
  else
    echo "BADDD";
  //call our embedded procedure to add the video to the database
  mysql_query("call SaveImage($studyId, $sonogram)");
  mysql_error();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated there is a ton of code associated with this form so I am only posting the relevant portion.  I have multiple check boxes and text boxes in the same form and they are all submitting correctly so I am pretty sure the problem lies with the "file" portion

Comment: is that all of your code?? is there a form associated with that input??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your form Set:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="youractionurl">
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

you must use a multipart-form to upload a file 
ex:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Now you should access $_FILES from the page named upload.php

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to check the size of the files you are uploading. There are several places where you have to define the appropriated size. As mentioned above the MAX_FILE_SIZE on the form is one. You have also to check on the php.ini file the available memory for your script (memory_limit)  and the available processing time (max_input_time, max_execution_time )  and the maximum size of you post requests (post_max_size). These can be changed either directly on your php.ini or using a htaccess file.